# select theme for android phone programatically

Tags: android, themes

Hi I want to create an android application which displays list of themes(Not the default themes shown in personalize menu in the phone) and user must select the theme which in turn changes the theme of the android phone.

Is this possible? If yes kindly tell how and give me links for the code samples for doing this.

Comment: Just curios, where did you find "personalize" menu? It seems like there is no such thing in Android Settings.

Comment: @inazaruk:you can find the personalize option when u press the menu button in android phone

Comment: @androidGuy: I can't see this menu on any of the phones I have :)

Comment: @inazruk:I checked out with HTC Desire HD.Is it possible to change the skin/theme programatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible to do in a third party application.

Comment: Thanks for ur immediate response,so can we programatically add the new themes to the already existing list of themes for android phone?

Comment: Android currently doesn't support dynamic "themes".  (Actually this is not what themes are; this kind of dynamic modification of the look of the UI is something we would call skinning.)